# Error in Taylor's Series using Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

How many terms should be used in taylor series expansion of the function f(z) = e^z around z = 0 for a specific value of z = 30 + 30 i to get an error of less than 0.05 using Mathematica?

`Poly[x_ , n_] := Series[Exp[x] , {x,0,n}] errorTaylor[x_ , n_] := (1/Factorial[n])*Integrate[((x-t)^n)*Exp[t],{t,0,x}] Reduce[{errorTaylor[30+30 I,n]<0.05},n,Complexes]`

The output was

°°° **Reduce** Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help.

`Reduce[{e^(30+30 I)(Gamma[1+n]-Gamma[1+n,30+30 I])/(n!)<0.05 if Re[n]>-1},n, **C**]`

How to rectify the code? What should I do? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Poly[x_, n_] := Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, n}]

 errorTaylor[x_, n_] := Assuming[n > -1,
  (1/Factorial[n])*
   Integrate[((x - t)^n)*Exp[t], {t, 0, x}]]

Table[errorTaylor[30 + 30 I, n], {n, 1, 3}] // N

(* {1.6484*10^12 - 1.05586*10^13 I, 1.6484*10^12 - 1.05586*10^13 I, 
 1.6484*10^12 - 1.05586*10^13 I} *)
```

You cannot use an inequality with a complex number. Compare to the absolute value of the error.

```
Reduce[Abs[errorTaylor[30 + 30 I, n]] < 1/20, n, Complexes]

(* Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. *)
```

Use a numeric technique, e.g., [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
sol = Ceiling[
  n /. FindRoot[Abs[errorTaylor[30 + 30 I, n]] == 1/20, {n, 50}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]]

(* 115 *)
```

Verifying,

```
Abs[errorTaylor[30 + 30 I, n]] /. n -> sol // N

(* 0.0241457 *)

Abs[errorTaylor[30 + 30 I, n - 1]] /. n -> sol // N

(* 0.066385 *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had been racking my brains out for the last few days. Thank you!